# How to fix input type='date' on mobile shows incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, input

I have a Todo application using react. I am still fairly new. And this is my first app. I used tailwind css for styling. And using typescript. I am using chrome on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. This is how it is showing on my mobile device using chrome and edge.

Mobile Input:

[image]

But on desktop it is showing fine:
[image]

This is my code. At first I didn't use any place holder. The date input was showing incorrectly. After giving place holder it still didn't work.

```
     <input
          required
          name="date"
          value={taskObj.date}
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          type="date"
          placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
          min={new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]}
          className="input-box inline-flex justify-center sm:block md:col-span-1"
          />
```

and this is the form tag

```
<form
className="grid w-full gap-2 py-3 md:grid-cols-4 xl:w-full 2xl:w-2/4"
onSubmit={onInputSubmit}
>
```

From [text](https://lightrun.com/answers/aws-amplify-amplify-ui-textfield-typedate-does-not-display-correctly-on-mobile) I use the inline-flex style using tailwind css. But still it isn't working.

Mobile solution:
[image]

This is the style I am using.

```
.input-box {
  @apply rounded-lg border border-slate-900 p-2 text-lg md:text-xl;
}
```

Here is my github repo link. [text](https://github.com/adnansyed101/reactTodoist). The input field is in src/components/Inbox.tsx line 97.

Comment: Could you change sm:block to sm:col-span-1 and let me if it works..

Comment: try remove all "md" from the className

Comment: can you add link to Codepan or somewhere else?

Comment: @RaphaelBenHamo I tried removing all the 'md' it still didn't not work. I don't know how to use codepen. I am still learning a lot. Its been only 6 months. I dont know how to post a local directory to codepen.

Comment: @VarunKaklia I tried but it still didn't work. I also have updated my question and have given the form tag too.

Comment: try remove all css ans put each one by one separately, this way you can identify what cause the problem in mobile mode